# Remove All trusted applications from a keychain item

Tags: objective-c, macos, keychain

I wrote the below code to add a generic password from my app. SecKeychainAddGenericPassword() adds the app as a trusted application in the keychain by design.
I want to remove my app from the list of trusted apps. I called SecKeychainItemSetAccess () to do that but I still see my app listed as a trusted app.

```
 addgenericpassword(const std::string& service,const std::string& account,
const std::string& password) {
      SecKeychainItemRef item_ref;
      OSStatus status = SecKeychainAddGenericPassword(NULL,
                                                      service.length(),
                                                      service.data(),
                                                      account.length(),
                                                      account.data(),
                                                      password.length(),
                                                      password.data(),
                                                      &item_ref);

    //Creating an secAccess object that has an empty trusted application list
    //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1393522-secaccesscreate?language=objc
      CFArrayRef applicationList=CFArrayCreate (NULL,NULL,0,NULL);
      SecAccessRef accessref;
      CFStringRef description=CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "Generic description", kCFStringEncodingASCII);

      status = SecAccessCreate(description,applicationList,&accessref);

      //Set the access of a keychain item "item_ref".
      status = SecKeychainItemSetAccess(item_ref,accessref);

      CFRelease(item_ref);
      CFRelease(accessref);
      CFRelease(applicationList);
      CFRelease(description);
      return 0;
    }
```

Update:
Changed description to match the service name. Still no luck

```
CFStringRef description=CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, service.data(), kCFStringEncodingASCII);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the functionality I was looking for.I am not sure if this is the right method to do it though.

```
    SecAccessRef accessref;
    SecKeychainItemCopyAccess(item_ref, &accessref);
    CFArrayRef aclList;
    SecAccessCopyACLList(accessref, &aclList);

    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(aclList);
    //Array with 0 Applications / Empty Array . Not the same as passing NULL
    CFArrayRef zero_applications = CFArrayCreate(NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        SecACLRef acl = (SecACLRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(aclList, i);
        CFArrayRef applicationList;
        CFStringRef description;
        CSSM_ACL_KEYCHAIN_PROMPT_SELECTOR promptSelector;
        SecACLCopySimpleContents(acl, &applicationList, &description,
                                  &promptSelector);
       if (applicationList == NULL) {
         continue;
       }
        CFIndex appCount = CFArrayGetCount(applicationList);

        for (int j = 0; j < appCount; j++) {
          status= SecACLSetContents(acl, zero_applications, description, 1);
          break;
        }
        CFRelease(applicationList);
        CFRelease(description);
    }

  // Set the modified copy to the item now
  status = SecKeychainItemSetAccess(item_ref, accessref);
```